# Bootstrap DatePicker-Month View Error

Tags: javascript, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker with month view as below.

```
$('#track_datepicker').datepicker({
              autoclose: true,
              viewMode: "months", 
              minViewMode: "months",
              format: "mm/yyyy"
              });
```

But this code doesn't show the full calendar view just shows names of months
The view is as below.
[image: datepicker view]

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout this fiddle mention below:

http://jsfiddle.net/k5zookLt/2865/

HTML :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>First check in:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-1 input-sm from" placeholder="CheckIn" >
</div>
```

JS :

```
$('.from').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    minViewMode: 1,
    format: 'mm/yyyy'
})
```

Version of Bootstrap Calander:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js

Please add css for proper view :
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css

please check it out.